# Python3 - Invalid JSON payload

Tags: python, json, parsing

I make api request with my variable and get an error:

```
{"error":{"code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"Invalid JSON payload","data":[{"name":"cause","code":"","value":"json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]json.RawMessage","message":""}]}}
```

but if I manually copy-paste value of this variable to data1 as string - all ok. What is the mistake?

```
def fastStockUpdate() :  
    data1 = {'stocks': [{'product_id': 678904, 'offer_id': 'NSIN0013720152', 'stock': 0}, {'product_id': 678895, 'offer_id': 'NSIN0013720163', 'stock': 0}]}
    data2 = tempStockLine
    
    url = 'http://api-seller.ozon.ru/v1/product/import/stocks'
    print(data1)
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'api-seller.ozon.ru', 'Client-Id': 'xx',
               'Api-Key': 'xx'}
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data1)
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Use double quotes as suggested below. Also, you'll need API keys for this request.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
data1 = {"stocks": [{"product_id": 678904, "offer_id": "NSIN0013720152", "stock": 0}, {"product_id": 678895, "offer_id": "NSIN0013720163", "stock": 0}]}
```

Comment: the same problem. if i copy paste str from variable and put manually to data(data1), request is completed and i get good answer. but if i connect to data str variable - i get error